# How to travel into an ArrayOfXelement?

Tags: c#, silverlight, datatable, xelement

I get an ArrayOfXelement for a result by a webservice. But now I wish to bind this data into a chart in Silverlight also I need to create a datatable.

My question is how to travel my ArrayOfXelement ? Any ideas ? Linq to XML ?

Regards.

Narglix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a `foreach` loop?

Comment: It's okay I found it : foreach (XElement el in tab.Nodes) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
void service_GetItemInfoCompleted(object sender, GetCartsOutDsCompletedEventArgs e)
{

        var result = e.Result.Nodes;
}
```